# Connect Sql Azure with Android

Tags: android, sql-server, azure

**How can I connect database?**

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

String connectionString = "jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxx.database.windows.net:1433;database=navili;user=xxxxxx;password=xxxxx;encrypt=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;";
Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;
PreparedStatement prepsInsertPerson = null;
PreparedStatement prepsUpdateAge = null;

try {

    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
    /*String selectSql = "SELECT Username, Password FROM dbo.System_Users";
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(selectSql);*/

    // Iterate through the result set and print the attributes.
    /*while (resultSet.next()) {
        System.out.println(resultSet.getString(2) + " "
                + resultSet.getString(3));
    }*/
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    // Close the connections after the data has been handled.
    if (prepsInsertPerson != null) try { prepsInsertPerson.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
    if (prepsUpdateAge != null) try { prepsUpdateAge.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
    if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
    if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
    if (connection != null) try {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        connection.close();} catch(Exception e) {}
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Error Message

> com.example.tao.navi W/System.err:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not
>   establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets
>   Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Socket closed".

**Azure Server already allowed ip addresse**

Answer (score 0):

If you are on android you do not want to connect to a sql server directly. When you have the connection string like you have now, anybody can get it from your application and do queries on you sql server. This will expose all you data to everyone. You normally put a server (web server) between you android application and your sql server. The server handles the security and business logic for saving etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this at the end of your connection URL `;ssl=request`

And if your are using jtds libraries then also add `jtds:` after `jdbc:` in your connection url

and also change `database=navili;` to `DatabaseName=navili;`